# Not able to add a project ID/name to a list in Jira/Groovy/Scriptrunner

Tags: groovy, jira, scriptrunner-for-jira

The following question I present is the following: I'm doing a code that is been tested in the Scriptrunner console and tried into Jira. What I want to reach is the following: I have an issue in any project, at any moment a workflow transition allows me to copy the current issue and all the linked issues in a new project.

The cfProjectPicker is a custom field Project Picker that allows me to select a project.
What I'm having trouble right now on the code is the following:

1- projectKey is returning null valor but projectPicker is returning the correct project selected in the custom field.

2- createNewIssue is not allowing me to recognize the "params" field as a mutable issue, and it is a mutable (if I replace with newIssue it does take it)

3- the list "issuesCopied" is not allowing me to issuesCopied.id.toString() but I'm guessing is giving error due to the point 2.

Any help regarding the matter would be much appreciated because I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong at moment.

```
def issueMgr = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager();
def issueTypeSchemeManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueTypeSchemeManager()
def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager();
def projectMgr  = ComponentAccessor.getProjectManager();
def groupManager = ComponentAccessor.getGroupManager();
def issueFactory = ComponentAccessor.getIssueFactory();
IssueLinkManager issueLinkManager  = ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager();

def cfProjectPicker = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Seleccionar Proyecto") //cf project picker
def issue = issueMgr.getIssueObject("MART1-1")

ApplicationUser user = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser() //User Admin
ApplicationUser currentUser = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser()
def currentIssue = issueFactory.getIssue()
//def issue = issueMgr.getIssueObject()
def newIssue = issueFactory.getIssue()
def exit = false

// Array list of the issues created to save them
List<String> issuesCopied = new ArrayList<>();

// ***** CREATE ISSUE *****

if (issuesCopied.isEmpty()){
    
    String projectPicker = issue.getCustomFieldValue(cfProjectPicker)
    log.error("Gengar")
    log.error(projectPicker)
    def projectKey = projectMgr.getProjectObjByKey(projectPicker)
    log.error(projectKey)
    newIssue.setProjectObject(projectKey)
    newIssue.setIssueType(issue.getIssueType())
    newIssue.setSummary(issue.getSummary())
    newIssue.setDescription(issue.getDescription())
    newIssue.setReporter(currentUser)
    def params = ["issue":newIssue]
    log.error(params)
    def createNewIssue = issueMgr.createIssueObject(user,params);

    issuesCopied.add(createNewIssue.id.toString())

}
```

Comment: Hey Yuri, can you provide some example console output in order to understand problem that you faced?

Comment: No worries @stuck I did solve it so it's fine. Thank for the help tho!